# WCF client unable to connect to WCF server with error

Tags: c#, wcf

I am unable to connect my WCF client to my WCF server on a Localhost network. The error that I am getting is the following:

> Error while connecting to the Localhost server: Could not find default
>        endpoint element that references contract 'MyServiceReference.IMyService' 
>        in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because 
>        no configuration file was found for your application, or because no 
>        endpoint element matching this contract could be found in the client element.

The server connection is the following. Here is the code:

```
 _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

 //Create Metadata exchange for the service
 ServiceMetadataBehavior mexBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
 _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(mexBehavior);

 //Add service endpoints for the service and mex
 _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/WFC_Server/MyService.svc");
 _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange), MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding(), "net.pipe://localhost/WFC_Server/MyService.svc/mex");
 _host.Open();
```

I am not setting up my client to connect to the server properly. Does anybody know why? Here is the code:

```
 var callback = new MyServiceCallback();
 var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(callback);
 var client = new MyServiceReference.MyServiceClient(instanceContext);
 client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/WFC_Server/MyService.svc");
            client.OpenSession();
```

Does anybody know why my client does not connect to the server?

Comment: Have you in client config endpoint for this service?

Comment: The client works if I leave the WCF connection under App.config file but when I try to replicate the App.config file to .CS coding its giving me a hard time

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Just change the address of the service?

Comment: Start the service for the client side. The server is currently running on my computer, I want to connect the client to the server.

Comment: Look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133(v=vs.110).aspx). You need to add reference to service in client app and use it.

Comment: Can you please post servers app.config file, where service is configured

Comment: I changed my post to show the server connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replicated the problem and fixed the issue.
1. Specify the endpoint address while creating the client.

```
 var callback = new MyServiceCallback();
                var instanceContext = new InstanceContext(callback);
                EndpointAddress remoteAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/WFC_Server/MyService.svc");
                var client = new MyServiceClient(instanceContext,new NetNamedPipeBinding(),remoteAddress);
                client.Hello(); // call the function
```

2. In the server, you can register like this:

Code:

```
            Uri address1 = new Uri("http://localhost/WFC_Server/");
            Uri address2 = new Uri("net.pipe://localhost/WFC_Server/");
            ServiceHost _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService), address1,address2);

            //Create Metadata exchange for the service
            ServiceMetadataBehavior mexBehavior = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            mexBehavior.HttpGetEnabled = true;
            _host.Description.Behaviors.Add(mexBehavior);


            //Add service endpoints for the service and mex
           _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), "MyService.svc");

            _host.AddServiceEndpoint(
              ServiceMetadataBehavior.MexContractName,
              MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(),
              "mex"
            );
            _host.Open();
```

I have used the following interfaces as an example:

```
  class MyService : IMyService
    {
        public void Hello()
        {
         Console.WriteLine("Hello From Server..");
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ICallbackService))]
    internal interface IMyService
   {
        [OperationContract]
        void Hello();
    }


    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ICallbackService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void CallClient();
    }
```